# Setting up Fargate Task Definition in CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-fargate

I am trying to set up a task definition for a Fargate container running from the latest image in a ECR repository. However, I can't really get it to work. I am having this code so far:

```
    const Repository = new ecr.Repository(this, 'Repository');
    const TaskDefinition = new ecs.FargateTaskDefinition(this, "TaskDefinition", {})

    TaskDefinition.addContainer("Container", {
      image : ecs.EcrImage.fromEcrRepository(Repository, "latest")
    })
```

However when I run it, I get  Argument of type 'Repository' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IRepository'. I tried following the documentation and have tried writing it a few different ways, but always the same error.

Comment: What does your package.json look like? What versions of  cdk packages are you using?

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "@aws-cdk/aws-codecommit": "^1.114.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-dynamodb": "^1.114.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-iam": "^1.114.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda": "^1.114.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-event-sources": "^1.114.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-s3": "^1.114.0",
    "@aws-cdk/core": "^1.114.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-ecr": "^1.114.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-ecs": "^1.114.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-ssm": "^1.114.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.16"
  }

Comment: Hmm thats strange. Usually these errors arise from having different cdk package versions. Can you try to delete the node modules folder and running an npm or yarn install again? Sometimes that works for me.

Comment: I tried doing that, but now I cant install any package. It complains about npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall rename. Its strange as I did not have this problem with my stack before introducing ecs

Comment: I got it to work. I pushed everything to a repository, then created a new folder locally and pulled all the code to that folder. Now npm install works. Must have been some permission issues in the old folders

Comment: I would not recommend using carrots with versions in cdk as you can get these version mismatches if you add a new dependency after a new release has been done (even if you're using ^1.114.0 for everything in package.json.  I'm guessing if you had looked at your package-lock or yarn lock you'd have seen the ECR version was different from the ECS version